# SQL Join query brings multiple results

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables. One lists all the goals scored in the English Premier League and who scored it and the other, the squad numbers of each player in the league.

I want to do a join so that the table sums the total number of goals by player name, and then looks up the squad number of that player.

Table A [goal_scorer]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alWxh.png)

Table B [squads]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H651N.png)

I have the SQL query below:

```
SELECT goal_scorer.*,sum(goal_scorer.number),squads.squad_number 
FROM goal_scorer 
Inner join squads on goal_scorer.name=squads.player 
group by goal_scorer.name
```

The issue I have is that in the result, the sum of 'number' is too high and seems to include duplicate rows. For example, Aaron Lennon has scored 33 times, not 264 as shown below.

[image]

Comment: Could you include the tables as text instead of a link to an image provider? Some of us are behind a firewall which censors sites like the one you are using (imgur).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this?

```
SELECT goal_scorer.*, s.total, squads.squad_number 
FROM goal_scorer 
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT name, sum(number) as total
  FROM goal_scorer
  GROUP BY name
) s on s.name = goal_scorer.name
JOIN squads on goal_scorer.name=squads.player
```

There are other ways to do it, but here I'm using a sub-query to get the total by player.  NB:  Most modern SQL platforms support windowing functions to do this too.

Also, probably don't need the left on the sub-query (since we know there will always be at least one name), but I put it in case your actual use case is more complicated.

Comment: Hi - yep, this fixed the problem. I still had a case of multiple results so I added a 'group by id' after the 'JOIN' and it seems to have fixed it. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this if you are using **sql-server**?

```
select * 
from squads
outer apply(
            selecr sum(goal_scorer.number) as score
            from goal_scorer where goal_scorer.name=squads.player
           )x
```

Comment: Hi - i'm using a local MySQL - I think it's MariaDB